# NPM workspaces with Expo and Typescript

Tags: typescript, npm, babeljs, expo, npm-workspaces

I'm trying to use NPM 7 workspaces within a Typescript Expo project.
For now I want to keep the normal Expo structure (with the root `App.tsx` file), but I want to isolate some parts of the code in workspaces.

I have issues to compile the TS code within the workspaces. I tried many things to configure the TS and/or Webpack configs but without success. So here is the minimal file structure to reproduce it:

```
package.json
tsconfig.json
App.tsx
/packages
  /core
    index.ts
    package.json
```

**Here is the relevant part of the root `./package.json`**

```json
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {...},
  "dependencies": {...},
  "devDependencies": {...},
  "private": true
}
```

**The `./tsconfig.json` is the bare minimum**

```json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

**The `./packages/core/package.json` is very simple as well**

```json
{
  "name": "core",
  "private": true
}
```

**And the `./packages/core/index.ts` simply exports a `log()` function for this example**

```
export function log(s: string) {
  console.log(s)
}
```

**Finally, in `./App.tsx`, is simply imports the function an try calling it**

```
import { log } from 'core'
log('hello')
//...
```

#### It doesn't compile

When I try to build for the web (with `expo build:web` for instance) I have the following error

```
✖ Expo Webpack
  Compiled with some errors in 1.62s

Failed to compile.

[path]/node_modules/core/index.ts 1:21
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:21)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> export function log(s: string) {
|   console.log(s)
| }
```

I'm not surprised because the `/node_modules` directory is willingly excluded.

So my question is **what do I need to do in order to get the workspaces code compiled**? I'd like it to work on the fly (ie: not precompiled) just like if it was some regular files in my project. Is it doable at all?

#### Some failed attempts to fix it

I mainly tried to tweak the tsconfig to get it to work (although I kind wonder if it changes anything)

#### #1

I tried adding `"include": ["./node_modules/core"],` in `./tsconfig.json`. **It had no effect** (same error).

#### #2

I tried to create the following `/packages/core/tsconfig.json` with the composite option:

```json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "composite": true
  }
}
```

And referenced it in the root `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  },
  "references": [{ "path": "./node_modules/core" }]
  // or even with:
  "references": [{ "path": "./packages/core" }]
}
```

**It had no effect** (same error).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a solution that I'm not super happy with but at least it's working. It's actually quite straightforward, I simply configured Webpack to compile my `packages/*` (as symlinks in the `node_modules`.

So first I installed:

```sh
$ npm i -D ts-loader@8 webpack@4.430
```

Versions are important here to be consistent with the webpack version used by Expo 41.

I also renamed my package name (in `/packages/core/package.json`) to something like `@workspace/core` so that all my custom packages are inside the `node_modules/@workspace` directory.

It will also make our config simpler.

Running `$ expo customize:web` is necessary to customize the webpack config. It will produce a `webpack.config.js`.

It can be customised as follow:

```js
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config')

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv)

  config.module.rules = [
    {
      // this is why I renamed my packages with the @workspaces prefix.
      test: /node_modules\/@workspaces\/(.*)\.ts$/, 
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          // force ts-loader to compile in node_modules
          options: { allowTsInNodeModules: true },
        },
      ],
    },
    ...config.module.rules,
  ]

  return config
}
```

I wouldn't be surprised if there was a cleaner solution. But for now I'll stick to it